# What is the alternative for getMonthValue(),getDayOfMonth() in java 7?

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS");
Date date = new Date();
```

How Do I make this Java 7 compatible? What changes should I do?

```
String part = date.getYear() + "" + String.format("%02d", date.getMonthValue()) + ""
        + String.format("%02d", date.getDayOfMonth()) + "" + String.format("%02d", date.getHour()) + ""
        + String.format("%02d", date.getMinute()) + "" + String.format("%02d", date.getSecond());
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but *public int getMonth()
Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH).*

Comment: You can use [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) in Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

The terrible `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat` classes were supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 and built into Java 8+.

No need to hack together the output string. Use a `DateTimeFormatter` object instead.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now() ;
String output = 
    zdt
    .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS )
    .format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ) ;
```

For Java 6 and 7, add the back-port of *java.time* to your project, the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library. The API is nearly identical to *java.time*, so later upgrading your project to modern Java will involve little more than changing the `import` statements.

As you may know, [Java 6 and 7 are years past their end-of-life](https://endoflife.date/java). I suggest you consider migrating to Java 8, 11, or 17, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SimpleDateFormat` if upgrading Java (from version 7) is not possible and to avoid any external library:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Date date = new Date();
String part = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Pattern can be changes as needed: see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of the `SimpleDateFormat` class.

As already advised in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061837/16320675), upgrade to a newer Java and then use the classes from `java.time` package and sub-packages (like `DateTimeFormatter`).